# Jquery empty() div except for matched elements

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to empty a div leaving only elements with a specific class name? Or, is there a way to remove all elements within a div leaving only elements with a specified class?

Comment: if Marve's answer solves the problem you should accept it, by clicking the check mark near his answer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#theDiv').find('*').not('.className').remove();
```

Sample markup:

```
<div id="theDiv">
    <p>this will be removed</p>
    <p class="className">this will stay</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jason - I'm all for Marve's answer - but what if they both work? He should accept the answer that is most useful to him.

Comment: It's worth noting that `.find('*')` will target all descendents, irrespective of whether they are contained within an element specified in `.not()`. Put another way, if you have specified an element using `.not()` and it contains children, they will not be exempt from `.remove()` and will be removed also. In that case, `children()` may be more useful in place of `.find('*')`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another option using just jQuery selectors:

```
$("#theDiv *:not('.className')").remove();
```

The issue with a method like this and those above is if there are any child elements they will also be removed, for example:

```
<div id="theDiv">
    <p>this will be removed</p>
    <p class="className"><strong>this will also be removed :(</strong></p>
</div>
```

The **this will also be removed :(** text will be removed as well because it is matched the wildcard * and does not have the class **className**. In order to solve this we would want to only filter direct children of the parent, such as:

```
$("#theDiv > *:not('.className')").remove();
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer is much better than the accepted one IMO.

Comment: This rocks. I didn't think about not selector!

Answer (score 1):

@Marve's way is probably better, but here's another anyway (using [filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter)):

```
$("#yourDiv").html($('#yourDiv').filter('.IWantThisClass, .IWantThisToo').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#theDiv').find('*:not(".className")').remove();
```